# Soaked chickpeas overnight 12 hours not plump

Tags: food-safety, beans

The dried chickpeas had two methods for soaking. Boiling and soaking, about 2hrs, and soaking overnight.

I placed chickpeas in bowl of water overnight in fridge for about 12 hrs. They still seam "hard". How soft are chickpeas to get when soaked overnight? Can chickpeas get "old"?

Comment: I never soaked chickpeas while keeping them in fridge. Mabe it's just the matter of low temperature. Usually recipes call just for soaking overnight, I asume in room temperature.

Answer (score 2):

Chickpeas **can** get old, however, after an overnight soak, though they may be hydrated they are still not yet cooked.
That means they will still be firm, possibly very firm.

Rather than trying to guess at this point whether or not they are old, just cook them to instructions & see how they come out.
It's really not that easy to tell old beans/pulses before you cook them. Even if a *bit* old, you can often cook them down given sufficient time.

Comment: Does the boil and sit method not actually cook the beans as well? It as well simply hydrates the beans faster?

Comment: It hydrates faster, but is less satisfying overall, long soak is better. It doesn't cook. An hour or so at simmer will cook [or equivalent pressure cook]. Many beans/pulses also need a 10 min rapid boil to kill off any toxins [I think it's oxalic acid, but not certain] so to avoid having to remember which must & which don't need it [iirc chickpeas don't need it], it's simpler to always do it. Boil 10, simmer 60 - 90mins.

Comment: Of the common beans only red kidney beans need a hard boil, and the issue is phytohaemaglutinin